# Question about proving: If $x \in \omega$ and $y \in x$, then $ y \in \omega$

Tags: set-theory

Theorem: $x \in \omega$ and $y \in x$ then $ y \in \omega$

Proof: By induction.

Base step: $ \phi(\emptyset)$ holds "since its first universal quantifier rangers over the empty set."

Questions: I do not understand why the base step holds. Can someone please explain how I am to make sense of the justification given above in quotes? While $\emptyset \in \omega$ (the natural numbers), it does not make sense to me to claim that there exists some $y \in \emptyset$ such that $y \in \omega$, because there is nothing in the empty set. Where has my reasoning gone wrong?

Comment: By induction on what? $x$, $y$ or what? I.e., what is $\phi$? If $\phi = \phi(x)$ is $\forall y(x \in \omega \land y \in x \Rightarrow y \in \omega)$, then $\phi(\emptyset)$ is true because the antecedent of the implication is false.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The statement $y\in\emptyset$ is false. Hence the statement "$\emptyset\in\omega$ and $y\in\emptyset$" is false. Since this is the antecedent of the statement you wish to prove, the statement is vacuously true. Recall $p\to q$ is true whenever $p$ is false.